# Unable to update a nullable integer column to zero - saves as null

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In Laravel 5.3, given the MySQL column:

```
$table->integer('score')->nullable();
```

When the value is zero, confirmed by debugging request, null gets inserted by eloquent.

When updating I call this on the model:

```
$this->update(['score' => 0]);
```

All other fields update correctly as expected. And this score field saves values greater than zero fine. I've tried passing it both '0' and 0. And tried using the save function and passing a request.

Unless I'm missing something it's like eloquent is forcing 0 be null. This is a problem for me as in some context I need null (e.g. saving a draft) and other times 0 (a final score).

**Edit:**

Resolved. My bad, one of the parent models had some custom code overriding default Laravel behaviour.

Comment: On a fresh install (5.3), I'm not able to reproduce the issue, on creation or update of the value. Do you have a mutator on your model which could explain the issue ?

Comment: Legend. You were right, one of the custom models I was extending has some custom functions in there doing crazy things with nulls!